# 'OrderByDescending' not recognizing in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net mvc & I'm trying to make a website where user can sort a table after login. When I build the project I get errors like, `Does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending'/'OrderBy'/'ToList'`. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.CodeSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "code_desc" : "";
        var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.AsQueryable() };     //Error in this line

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "code_desc":
                sortedOut = sortedOut.OrderByDescending(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);   //error in this line
                break;
            default:
                sortedOut = sortedOut.OrderBy(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);    //error in this line
                break;
        }
        return View(sortedOut.ToList());   //error in this line
```

**Model**

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public IQueryable<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }
    public idx Idxs { get; set; }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the IQueryable is the `mkistats`, not the `sortedOut`!

```
ViewBag.CodeSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "code_desc" : "";
var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.AsQueryable() };     //Error in this line

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "code_desc":
        sortedOut.mkistats = sortedOut.mkistats.OrderByDescending(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);   //error in this line
        break;
    default:
        sortedOut.mkistats = sortedOut.mkistats.OrderBy(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);    //error in this line
        break;
}
return View(sortedOut);   //error in this line
```

And the switch is wrong, but I am not sure how to solve it. It should probably be

```
switch (ViewBag.CodeSort)
```

Note that as the code is written, the view will only receive a `List<mkistat>`, not a full `MkistatVsUserLogin` object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I get this error whenever I try to login by using my project, `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MyMvc.Models.mkistat]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyMvc.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin'.]` How can I fix this?

Comment: @SinOscuras Try changing the return to: `return View(sortedOut)`

Answer (score 0):

OrderByDescending is an extension method inside of System.Linq.

Make sure you have the relevant using statemenet at the top of your class

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I've this on both of my model & controller class.